# Use of "PR" as a verb

Tags: word-usage, verbs, slang, abbreviations, antimeria

I have heard the term "PR" used as a verb, but have not found this in the dictionary.  The way it was used seemed to me to be a derogatory way to imply the use of public relations techniques in a less than honest or straight forward way.

Example: "Joe from the Acme Corporation is just trying to PR you. They will never get the job done in time."

Is there an actual dictionary definition that fits this meaning and usage?

Comment: It's a classical case of "verbification" of a noun.  Not "correct" in a formal context, but very well understood.

Comment: 1)noun) Runner's jargon for Personal Record, which is a person's best time in a particular event.

2)verb) To achieve a PR
1) My PR for the mile is 4:54

2) I PRed yesterday by three seconds. (Urban Dictionary:http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pr)

Comment: @mahmudkoya - I suspect that in the OP's case "PR" refers to ["public relations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_relations).

Comment: It is possibly a deliberate play on words, because people in PR are often guilty of "verbing", i.e. using nouns as verbs.

Comment: Related - RSP as a verb (render safe procedures) - https://english.stackexchange.com/a/309904/160746

Comment: @user221615 Is that how they came to invent the atrocious verb "to leverage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MetaEd actually answered my question [in a comment on 2 Mar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376268/use-of-pr-as-a-verb#comment882914_376268) by pointing me to a [WordReference.com discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/using-pr-as-a-verb.2470116) where the OP says this has entered English via Russian, where *PR* as a verb" has become common:

> Can I say *XXX (name of the company) donate money to charities, but they don't do it because they are so kind but to PR themselves*.
>
> I'm asking this **because 'PR' has found its place in the Russian language and we often use this word the way** like in the examples above (I mean colloquially).

Answer (score 2):

Evidently PR as a verb has been around for some time with the meaning of (1) *do public relations work* and it's not hard to see why it's also come to mean (2) to [*paper over*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paper%20over) an issue or problem (i.e., do nothing to solve it) or *to BS* or even [*flimflam*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flimflam) someone if you are "all talk." I find it strange that I haven't found a formal definition of the verb that addresses these meanings, but will add one if I do.

> ...but the reason that they have a difficult time recruiting minority
> persons is in part because of the image of the police department, and
> when this was echoed to the mayor and the city council and the police
> department by way of a press conference, they immediately decided that
> to change the image they would put up billboards saying Houston
> police officers are good people, or something to that effect, so they
> want **to PR the problem away** and you **cannot PR this type of
> negative image away**. [Oversight Hearings before the Committee on the
> D.C. House of Representatives, 96th Congress; *Problems in Urban
> Centers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings_Reports_and_Prints_of_the_House/Udg1AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20PR%20%20the%20problem%22&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover)  (**1980**)

> Even my own mother, who, upon hearing about one exciting upcoming
> project or another, has suggested that I do a good job of “**PR-ing**” for
> the client. [Allison Brinkman; **To PR or Not to PR: PR is Not a Verb!**"](https://www.cision.com/2010/04/to-pr-or-not-to-pr-pr-is-not-a-verb/) (2010)